# How to extract dynamic bearer token from the response in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have a requirement to get bearer token after login using Jmeter and want to use that token in other requests. I tried by passing user name and password and other query string parameter as shown in screen capture but it didn't work. it was giving following response

[Thread Name:Thread Group 1-1
Sample Start:2021-05-11 16:05:11 IST
Load time:2190
Connect Time:1550
Latency:2190
Size in bytes:160
Sent bytes:975
Headers size in bytes:155
Body size in bytes:5
Sample Count:1
Error Count:1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""):
Response code:415
Response message:Unsupported Media Type

HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType:
DataEncoding: null
]

I passed content-type as text/plain

Another challenge is token is unique for every user so how can I perform load test for different users?

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks[image]

Answer (score 0):

As per [415 Unsupported Media Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/415) status code description:

> The HTTP `415 Unsupported Media Type` client error response code indicates that the server refuses to accept the request because the payload format is in an unsupported format.

> The format problem might be due to the request's indicated [`Content-Type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) or [`Content-Encoding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Encoding), or as a result of inspecting the data directly.

My expectation is that for the HTTP Request sampler visible in your screenshot the relevant Content-Type header should be something like:

```
application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
```

If you have something different in the HTTP Header Manager - amend the value to the above one or disable/remove the HTTP Header Manager.

If you need to send different Content-Type (or other header) with different requests - put the HTTP Header Manager(s) **as the children** for the respective HTTP Request sampelrs. See [JMeter Scoping Rules - The Ultimate Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide) article for more information